Maximum Number of Possible Super keys in Relation Schema of N attributes where Candidate keys are greater than N/2
To find the Superkeys in the Relation with given Candidate keys, we can use Inclusion-Exclusion Principle
$
|A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n| = \sum_{i=1}^n |A_i| - \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j| + \sum_{1 \leq i < j < k \leq n} |A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k| - \dots + (-1)^{n+1} |A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_n|
$
This can be a good approach if the Candidate keys are less in the Relation Schema
$\text{R}\left( \text{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J} \right)$ . Example :-
Candidates Keys are $\text{R}\left( \text{A,B,C} \right)$. Using Inclusion- Exclusion :
$\left| \text{A}\bigcup_{}^{} \text{B} \bigcup_{}^{}\text{C}\right| = A + B + C - (A\cap B + B\cap C + C\cap A) + A\bigcap_{}^{}B\bigcap_{}^{}C$
We can easily calculate this. But in case of Candidate more than $\left\lfloor N/2 \right\rfloor$ , Using the Inclusion- Exclusion formula generate a lot of terms.
Example:-
Relation $\text{R}\left( \text{A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J} \right)$
Candidtae Keys are $\text{R}\left( \text{A, B, C, D, EF, FG} \right)$
Here Inclusion- Exclusion will generate a lot of terms. How can we solve such type of questions ?
